# Is it possible to write Flutter Windows app using Parallels Desktop on MacBook Pro M1?

Tags: windows, flutter, apple-m1, parallels

Until Bootcamp doesn't support M1 chip, I want to use Parallels Desktop to run Windows on my MacBook Pro M1.

Will I meet any obstacles with development of Windows application using Flutter on Parallels Desktop?

Answer (score 0):

If you have enough headroom, spec-wise, on your Mac it should be fine.

**Note that**:I'm using Intel, i don't know about M1,check this [Link](https://www.reddit.com/r/FlutterDev/comments/u24jmj/flutter_windows_on_mac_parallels/) for more information about flutter_windows_on_mac_parallels-> M1.